# How do I add an image in my Table in jQuery's

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, database, api

So I am trying to instead of have the svg links of images to have the image actually show in the table.
Can someone help me?

```js
var url3 = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/region/europe";
$.getJSON(url3, function (landen2, status) {
    //console.log("Data:", data);
    //console.log("Status:", status);
    laadTable(landen2);
});

function laadTable(landen2) {
    var landtable2 = $("<table>").addClass("tbl_sm");
    var tl2 = $("<tr>")
        .append($("<th>").html("name"))
        .append($("<th>").html("vlag"))
        .append($("<th>").html("neighboring countries"))
    landtable2.append(tl2);

    $(landen2).each(function (key, landen2) {
        var x = landen2.perc * 100;
        tl2 = $("<tr>")
            .append($("<td>").html(landen2.name))
            .append($("<td>").html(landen2.flag))
            .append($("<td>").html(landen2.borders))
        landtable2.append(tl2);
    });

    $("#divEind").append(landtable2);
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery CDN -->
    <div id="contentJA">
        <div id="divEind"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this simply build an `img` element and set the `landen2.flag` value as its `src`.

Also note that you can improve the performance of the JS by reducing the number of times you update the DOM. You can achieve this by creating HTML as strings and appending them once, and also using `map()` to build an array of the new `<tr>` to add in one operation instead of in each iteration of the loop.

```js
var url3 = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/region/europe";
$.getJSON(url3, function(landen2, status) {
  laadTable(landen2);
});

function laadTable(landen2) {
  let $table = $("<table>").addClass("tbl_sm");
  let $header = $("<tr><th>name</th><th>vlag</th><th>neighboring countries</th></tr>").appendTo($table);
  let rows = landen2.map(o => {
    let $row = $(`<tr><td>${o.name}</td><td><img src="${o.flag}" /></td><td><ul></ul></td></tr>`);
    let borders = o.borders.map(b => `<li>${b}</li>`);
    $row.find('ul').append(borders);
    return $row;   
  });
  $table.append(rows).appendTo('#divEind');
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery CDN -->
<div id="contentJA">
  <div id="divEind">
    Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 

Also, do you know how I can make a list of the neighboring countries? instead of it being this: MNE, GRC, MKD, KOS
I would like it to be: 
- MNE
- GRC
- MKD
- KOS

Comment: Sure, you can use the similar `map()` logic to loop through the `borders` array and output a `ul/li` list. I updated the answer to give you an example of that